# The method nanoTime() is undefined for the type System in GWT

Tags: gwt

While compiling my libgdx application in eclipse I keep getting this error:

```
 [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/C:/Users/Zorfie/Programing/Java/workspace/Libgdx/src/sim/states/BasicBox2DState.java'
      [ERROR] Line 157:  The method nanoTime() is undefined for the type System
      [ERROR] Line 159:  The method nanoTime() is undefined for the type System
      [ERROR] Line 160:  The method nanoTime() is undefined for the type System
      [ERROR] Line 161:  The method nanoTime() is undefined for the type System
   [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle_2.4.0.v201203300216-rel-r37/gwt-2.4.0/gwt-user.jar!/com/google/web/bindery/autobean/shared/impl/StringQuoter.java'
      [ERROR] Line 21:  The import org.json cannot be resolved
      [ERROR] Line 69:  JSONObject cannot be resolved
   [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle_2.4.0.v201203300216-rel-r37/gwt-2.4.0/gwt-user.jar!/com/google/web/bindery/autobean/vm/impl/JsonSplittable.java'
      [ERROR] Line 23:  The import org.json cannot be resolved
      [ERROR] Line 24:  The import org.json cannot be resolved
      [ERROR] Line 25:  The import org.json cannot be resolved
      [ERROR] Line 40:  JSONObject cannot be resolved to a type
      [ERROR] Line 47:  JSONObject cannot be resolved to a type
```

Which implies that GWT does not support .nanoTime(), is this the case or am I simply running with the wrong JRE? (I checked for the project and it said it was 1.6).

Comment: [`System.nanoTime()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime()) has been in the JDK since Java 1.5, so it's definitely not the case that your JRE is too old.

Comment: I have the same error with String.format. :D

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no support for `nanoTime()` in GWT since there is no support for it in javascript.

The closest analog in GWT is `Duration.currentTimeMillis()`

Comment: Let's also add a link to the docs: https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation